# In Applescript how do I read a website, and output the text as a variable?

Tags: applescript

In Applescript how do I read a website, and output the text as a variable?

I want to read the "Latest" number from [here](http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/sub-rel-mac/LATEST), then use that number to download the latest version of Chromium from [here](http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/sub-rel-mac/).

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct Applescript way, but this works well.

Create a shell script to do the download, say chrome-download.sh in your $HOME/bin directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
BUILD=`curl http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/sub-rel-mac/LATEST`
echo "Downloading build "$BUILD
curl http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/sub-rel-mac/$BUILD/chrome-mac.zip -o $HOME/chrome-mac-$BUILD.zip
```

Run it from Applescript (or Automator) in one line:

```
do shell script "/bin/bash /Users/<your username>/bin/chrome-download.sh"
```

The downloaded file lands in your $HOME directory.  The bash script will work from Linux or Cygwin, as well.  Of course, you could just run the bash script directly, too.

Answer (score 2):

As Glenn said it's much easier to just use a shell script and possibly wrap it in AppleScript by using `do shell script`. Another alternative if you want a GUI of sorts to the script is to look at a program called [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

Lastly if you're looking for a sample script that already does this I made one when Chromium Mac was announced a couple days back: http://chealion.ca/2009/05/chromium-build-bot-updater-script/ (Source on GitHub).

Answer (score 1):

A more AppleScript-native way would be:

```
set filePath to (path to temporary items folder as string) & "file.html"

tell application "URL Access Scripting"
    download "http://www.apple.com/sitemap/" to file filePath replacing yes
end tell

--read file into a variable
try
    open for access (file filePath)
    set fileData to (read file filePath)
    close access (file filePath)
on error errMsg number errNum
    try
        close access file filePath
    end try
    error errMsg number errNum
end try
```

You can find more information in the URL Access Scripting and StandardAdditions dictionaries. (File > Open Dictionary)